# freestyle vs wireframe viewport

Tags: rendering, freestyle, wireframe

hello kind blender stack exchange folks!

does anyone know any tips to make the freestyle match viewport wireframe?

I am new to blender, but I found I really like using wireframe mode to create these "line-art" style scenes. very basic, but looks kind of hand done. I know you can use the "Viewport Render Animation" or "Viewport Render Image" in the View Menu in Object mode, but I cant move the camera around if I just render the viewport animation. So, I've found out about Freestyle render options. The problem is I cant make it look just like the wireframe viewport... its close, but not the same. Or if someone knows how to move the camera around while doing a Viewport Animation render???

Here is a viewport render:

[image: here is the viewport render:]

and here is the best I can do with freestyle with Eevee (.4px lines and "Suggestive Contour" selected):

[image: freestyle render]

as you can see the wireframe viewport render is much better!

Comment: ha! nevermind! i just realized that if you are in "Camera Mode" in the viewport and you click "Render Viewport Animation" itll render it out from the camera view, duh!